# Custom newtab page: content script won't receive message from bgscript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am building a Chrome extension that injects some HTML and JS when the user clicks the extension icon. So, when the icon is clicked, it is registered in the bg script, and the content script is notified about this like so:

**Background script**

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(iconClicked)

function iconClicked(tab) {
  var visitors = window.AllVisitors.get(tab.id),
      data     = {
        message: 'toggleMenu',
        user: window.user
      };
  chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, data);
}
```

Now, to the **problem**: In my manifest file, I have also added a custom page for the `chrome://newtab` page. When the extension icon is clicked while visiting this custom newtab page, the content script does not receive any message what so ever. The default newtab page does actually receive the message as well as any other webpage.

I am thinking that maybe it has something to do with `externally_connectable`, but adding this does not help:

```
"externally_connectable": {
  "matches": ["chrome://newtab/"],
}
```

Does anybody know why my custom newtab page does not receive any messages from the background script? Any help is very appreciated!

**Manifest file:**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Orbit",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    "templates.html",
    "img/icon48.png",
    "fonts/*.woff",
    "img/*"
  ],
    "externally_connectable": {
      "matches": ["chrome://newtab/"],
    },
  "chrome_url_overrides" : {
    "newtab": "tab/newtab.html"
  },
  "icons": {
            "16": "img/icon16.png",
            "48": "img/icon48.png",
            "128": "img/icon128.png"
           },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": {
        "16": "img/icon16.png",
        "48": "img/icon48.png",
        "128": "img/icon128.png"
    },
    "default_title": "Orbit"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["vendor/chrome-promise.js", "vendor/jquery.js", "vendor/underscore.js", "vendor/backbone.js", "orbit.js"]
    },
    {
    "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
    "css": ["sidebar.css"]
  }
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["vendor/socket.io.js", "vendor/jquery.js", "vendor/underscore.js", "vendor/backbone.js", "vendor/chrome-promise.js", "vendor/jquery.js", "eventPage.js"],
    "persistent": true
  },
  "permissions": [
    "http://fonts.googleapis.com/*",
    "https://fonts.googleapis.com/*",
    "https://get-orbit.com:8080/*",
    "activeTab",
    "tabs",
    "storage"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Content scripts aren't injected on `chrome-extension://` pages.

Simply add the script manually in your newtab.html:

```
<html>
   <head>
       <script src="your-content-script.js"></script>
   </head>
```